# Similar concept to MediaWiki but with structured data fields

Tags: web-apps, cms, wiki, forms

I'm in the early stages of designing a non-commercial user-contributed website that hosts location, contact info, and reviews of local businesses (within a certain category).

I'd like to use a package like [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), but the articles aren't structured. For example, if a section is called "Hours" in one article, as far as I know, there is no way to constrain other articles to not include section names, such as "Opening times". Also, users editing an article aren't constrained to enter datetime objects as opening times, and instead could write "07-20" for one page and "7am to 8pm" for another page. In summary, I'd like the input to be structured.

I'm considering splitting the process by using Google Forms or similar upload tool to collect data and then some programming to stitch together the collected data with the site data.

- Is there any open source "Yelp"-like package for collecting, storing and displaying reviews?

OR

- Is there a MediaWiki-like tool that can constrain user input to certain data-types for certain fields?

If there isn't any one package, then preferred programming tools are MongoDB or similar, Python, or any SQL.

Comment: Maybe MediaWiki with a [form extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Form_extensions) would do the job?